# How to display and hide progress bar from fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've a fragment where I need to show progress bar on click of a button and remove the progress bar after successful completion of the task.

This is my fragment class' onCreateView method

```
private RelativeLayout view;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note, container, false);
    view = root;
    
    FloatingActionButton add = root.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectImage(context);
            displayProgressBar(true);
        }
    });


    hideKeyboard();

    return root;
}
```

This is the method I'm using to display and hide progressBar. But it's not working when I'm trying to hide the progressBar.

```
private void displayProgressBar(boolean visible) {
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.getActivity(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


    if (visible) {
        layout.addView(progressBar, params);
        MainActivity.getActivity().setContentView(layout);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        MainActivity.getActivity().setContentView(view);
    }

}
```

I've tried adding progressBar in my fragment's xml but it didn't quite work for me.
Here's the fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/note_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:hint="Double tap to type"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:id="@+id/taskText" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin_small"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm new to Android. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've tried resetting fragment view by:

```
MainActivity.getActivity().setContentView(view);
```

It's giving me following error:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.]

EDIT2:
Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    setBottomNavigation();
    savedState = savedInstanceState;
}

public void setBottomNavigation() {
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_files)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this,
            R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    navView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And MainActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would go for Binding Adapter to achieve this. See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us go through your code for the ProgressBar hiding and showing mechanism.

```java
private void displayProgressBar(boolean visible) {
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.getActivity(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


    if (visible) {
        layout.addView(progressBar, params);
        MainActivity.getActivity().setContentView(layout);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Your code is fine, what you are doing is creating a new Progress Bar on run time in your layout which is fine and good and it shows.

The thing is when you are trying to hide, you are not referencing the old `ProgressBar` in any way and instead you are just creating another `ProgressBar`. So to fix it I would suggest you keep a top level variable like

```java
 ProgressBar progressBar;
```

Then assign it and hide and show in your method.

Coming to XML, you can simply add it to your layout as follows

```xml
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Afterwards you would need to use `findViewById` to get a reference to the same and then you can simply hide it or show it as follows

```xml
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I need to remove the RelativeLayout – "layout" too and switch back to my fragment's view. This does not go back to previous view R.layout.fragment_note.

Comment: You should just keep the Progress Bar in the XML which you posted and use `findViewById` to find and then/show hide it accordingly. You do not need to add it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. But adding progressBar inXML. I'm getting this error layout/main_activity: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

Comment: Accepting your answer for suggesting the bug.

Answer (score -1):

I've got it working. The trick was to declare progressBar variable as a global variable as suggested by @che10.

Also I need to use XML's relative layout instead of initialising a new Relative layout. It may help someone:

```
private void displayProgressBar(boolean visible) {
    RelativeLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
    
    if (visible) {
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.getActivity(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        layout.addView(progressBar, params);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        layout.removeView(progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```